$n\ =\ \lfloor \sqrt{2}a\ \rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt{3}b\rfloor$

Prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ $,   \exists\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$
such that  $n\ =\ \lfloor \sqrt{2}a\ \rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt{3}b\rfloor
$

Honestly, I don't know where to get started on this question.
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1296841p6891886 I found this answer on AoPS, but I wasn't able to understand the cases for $n$ and why they work. An explanation of the given solution and hints towards an alternate solution would be nice.

To me, it seems a bit similar to the beatty sequence. (However, Rayleigh theorem doesn’t apply here - see the Beatty Sequence - Wikipedia if you’re interested.)

I have mentioned the Beatty Sequence in the comment, but seeing the AOPS post the solution there is quite clear and brief, so I’m posting an explanation of it.
First, OP on AOPS(OP below) wrote:
$$\text{For } \forall n \in \Bbb{N}, \exists b \in \Bbb{Z_0^+} \text{ s.t. }\sqrt{2}+b\sqrt{3}-2 < n \leq \sqrt{2}+b\sqrt{3}. $$
This is quite easy when you find that $\sqrt{3} < 2$. The interval of the range is 2, while the interval when $b$ varies is $\sqrt{3}$. So, the existence is quite trivial.
Then, using that $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x < \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$, we can say that $\lfloor \sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor b\sqrt{3} \rfloor - 2 < n < \lfloor \sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor b\sqrt{3} \rfloor + 2$.
Then the OP divided into 3 cases:

Case 1. $n = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor b\sqrt{3} \rfloor$
The case itself is the solution.

Case 2. $n = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor b\sqrt{3} \rfloor - 1$
Then, we can say that $n=\lfloor 0\sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor b\sqrt{3} \rfloor$.

Case 3. $n = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor b\sqrt{3} \rfloor + 1$
Then, we can say that $n=\lfloor 2\sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor b\sqrt{3} \rfloor$.

So, we are done.

"The interval of the range is 2, while the interval when b varies is $\sqrt{3}$." Can you elaborate on this?

@Illusioner_ No problem! Here's a simpler example - For $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}, \exists a \in \Bbb{Z_0^+}$ s.t. $a < n \leq a+2$. This is trivial, as the interval of the range is 2, while the interval when $a$ varies is 1. Just by lifting the interval in a variation of $a$(maintaining the fact that it is smaller than 2), you will get it.

Ah, yes. Also, I think in the AoPS post, there is a typo for case 1 that threw me off. It was written as $n = \lfloor \sqrt{2} \rfloor + b\lfloor \sqrt{3} \rfloor$. The $b$ wasn't inside the floor function. Is that a mistake or intentional

@Illusioner_ Oh well, that's a typo, maybe. That should have confused you. I hope my answer helped. (Besides, I would like to try for a Beatty Sequence... I'll post another answer if I find it.)
